# fpdf no me muestra los datos de algunas de mis consultas mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, fpdf

Es tal cual como dice el titulo, en mi PDF hago tres consultas y dos de ellas no las muestra, osea no aparece nada pero tampoco arroja ningún error, las consultas que no muestran nada son registros 1 y registros 2. No entiendo porque pasa esto así que acudo a su ayuda. Les dejo el código en cuestión:

```
session_start();
include('../../php/conexion.php');
include('../../pdf/fpdf.php');
if (isset($_COOKIE["id_cliente"])) {
    $_SESSION["id_cliente"]=$_COOKIE["id_cliente"];
}

if (isset($_SESSION["id_cliente"]) && isset($_GET["pedido"])) {

$registros1=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT pedido,producto,cantidad,precio_producto FROM pedidos WHERE pedido='$_GET[pedido]'");
$registros2=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM pedidos2 WHERE pedido='$_GET[pedido]'");
$fila2=mysqli_fetch_array($registros2);
$registros3=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nombre,apellido,direccion,codigoPostal,provincia FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente='$_SESSION[id_cliente]'");
$fila3=mysqli_fetch_array($registros3);


$pdf=new FPDF("P","pt","A4");
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetXY(30,210);
$pdf->SetFont("Times","",12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(280,13,utf8_encode($fila3["nombre"])." ".utf8_encode($fila3["apellido"]),0,0,"L");
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,102,255);
$pdf->SetFont("Times","B",12);
$pdf->Cell(95,13,"Numero Factura:",0,0,"L");
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFont("Times","",12);
$pdf->Cell(0,13,$fila2["pedido"],0,1,"L");

while ($fila1=mysqli_fetch_array($registros1)) {
    $pdf->SetX(30);
    $pdf->SetFont("Times","",9);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    $pdf->Cell(60,30,$fila1["cantidad"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(270,30,$fila1["producto"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(105,30,$fila1["precio_producto"],1,0,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(105,30,($fila1["cantidad"]*$fila1["precio_producto"]),1,1,"C");
}

$pdf->Output("factura.pdf","I");
```

Comment: Has comprobado que las consultas traen resultados? Para diferenciar si es un problema con la consulta o con el PDF. La consulta debería ser "SELECT .... pedido='".$_GET["pedido"]."' ", haz un var_dump o un echo del resultado para confirmar que estás trayendo los datos del pedido.

Comment: $fila1=NULL $fila2=NULL este fuel el resultado de var_dump.

Comment: Entonces el problema es la consulta, comprueba que si la lanzas directamente en MySQL te devuelve resultados.

Comment: hola, si era un problema en el envió de la consulta, pero ya lo solucione. Gracias por tu ayuda Carmen.